# Alternar 2 estilos CSS con un toggle HTML

Tags: html, css

actualmente tengo mi página con un toggle para cambiar a modo oscuro, unicamente agrego el `.dark` a los elementos que necesito.

Sin embargo, NO encuentro cómo hacer que mi toggle cambie por ejemplo de `index.css` a `index-oscuro.css`?

Es decir, el framework que utilizo sacó un `.css` con una versión dark ya lista, lo cual me facilita las cosas.

Hay forma de que se aplique `index.css` ó `index-oscuro.css` con un toggle?

Comment: Lo que pides tiene una complicación: debes reiniciar la pagina. Es decir... cambias el  .css programáticamente y luego debes reiniciarla (refrescarla) para que tome el cambio. El modelo anterior, simplemente era agregar una clase al body y listo. Lo hacia dinámicamente. Si es lo que buscas, confírmanos para poder ayudarte con la solución.

Comment: Si solo cambia los colores, el uso de variables en el css podría optimizar la conexión, ya que solo necesitarías utilizar un fichero css. De hecho, para cambiar en una página eso te permitiría no utilizar JS en absoluto… pero sí necesitas JS para conservar la preferencia del usuario al cambiar de página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el `href` al que apuntes con javascript puro sin recargar la página con:

```
const theme = document.getElementById("toggle-stylesheets-link");
theme.href = theme.getAttribute('href') === 'a.css' ? 'b.css' : 'a.css';
```

Donde en agregas la hoja de estilos así en tu `header` del `html` así:

```
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css" id="toggle-stylesheets-link">
</head>
```

> Es **muy recomentable** tener un css base en el que tengas los tamaños, tipos de letra y que `index.css` y `index-oscuro.css` solo cambien colores y fondos.

Hice una pequeña [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-bash-48r8r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) para que puedas apreciar mejor la estructura y como hacer el efecto toggle.

Comment: Man, de verdad muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda! De verdad estuve buscando como loco, de nuevo gracias